# "count" field is always "1" with custom JavaScript YQL Open Data Table

Tags: yql

YQL returns the number of records retrieved in its XML output:

```
<query xmlns:yahoo="http://www.yahooapis.com/v1/base.rng"
    yahoo:count="2" yahoo:created="2012-08-24T14:02:32Z" yahoo:lang="en-US">
    <diagnostics>
```

But I've been experimenting with my own custom [Open Data Tables](http://developer.yahoo.com/yql/guide/yql-opentables-chapter.html), at least ones which employ an `execute` block containing JavaScript to create the response, and no matter how I create the response the `count` field is always set to `1` when I make a query using the table.

I've also dug around in the documentation and can't seem to find anything addressing this.

**Is this by design? Is it a bug? Have I missed something obvious?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is commonly caused by *only returning one result*, which shouldn't really come as a surprise. The most usual cause of this, from my own experience, is forgetting to specify a suitable `itemPath` for the `<select>`.

Take the following examples, and see how the `response.object` structure and `itemPath` combine to give the query results.

#### Without an `itemPath`

```
<select itemPath="" produces="XML">
    <execute>
        <![CDATA[
        response.object = <letters>
            <letter>A</letter>
            <letter>B</letter>
            <letter>C</letter>
        </letters>
        ]]>
    </execute>
</select>
```

Produces a query result similar to:

```
<query xmlns:yahoo="http://www.yahooapis.com/v1/base.rng"
    yahoo:count="1" yahoo:created="…" yahoo:lang="en-US">
    <results>
        <letters>
            <letter>A</letter>
            <letter>B</letter>
            <letter>C</letter>
        </letters>
    </results>
</query>
```

#### With `itemPath="letters"`

```
<select itemPath="letters" produces="XML">
…
</select>
```

Produces a query result identical to the previous result.

```
<query xmlns:yahoo="http://www.yahooapis.com/v1/base.rng"
    yahoo:count="1" yahoo:created="…" yahoo:lang="en-US">
    <results>
        <letters>
            <letter>A</letter>
            <letter>B</letter>
            <letter>C</letter>
        </letters>
    </results>
</query>
```

#### With `itemPath="letters.letter"`

```
<select itemPath="letters.letter" produces="XML">
…
</select>
```

Note that now, the path now specifies a collection of `letter` items. This produces a query result similar to:

```
<query xmlns:yahoo="http://www.yahooapis.com/v1/base.rng"
    yahoo:count="3" yahoo:created="…" yahoo:lang="en-US">
    <results>
        <letter>A</letter>
        <letter>B</letter>
        <letter>C</letter>
    </results>
</query>
```

Comment: Aha! I hadn't taken into account the possibility that the problem lay in the way I was querying rather than in the way I put together the Open Data Table since the latter was the greater mystery to me.